# Can't install gsfonts-x11 or flashplugin-installer on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, flash

So I downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell mini Inspiron 910. Had problems with wifi, but I bought a wireless adapter and so I fixed that. But when I try installing flash, with `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer gsfonts-x11` it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gsfonts-x11 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-installer
E: Package 'gsfonts-x11' has no installation candidate
```

which I don't really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

That will install flash, and other goodies.

Comment: Just got `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Comment: Reboot, and try again.

Comment: Rebooting helped a lot but it didn't work still ` Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs` Got a lot of other stuff but I noticed that come up a few times, maybe has something to do with me using a usb as a flash drive to run the computer or something (still not great with computers). Then I got `E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)` so I tried that and got `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`

Comment: `E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

Comment: @Louis you should use `sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0):

try installing gsfonts-x11 package

Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install gsfonts-x11 deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install gsfonts-x11
```

Comment: Again, as I tried the first I got `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`
and again for the second `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just had to do `sudo reboot` then `sudo apt-get update` then go into Software Centre and download flash there.